# rsync hangs after 100% to-chk output

Tags: rsync, nfs, file-copy, nfsv4

I have an **NFS** mount of `/backup` and it is

```
type nfs4 (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,,clientaddr=192.168.1.2,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.1,_netdev)
```

when doing a `rsync -P ron.zip /bkup` it reports:

```
11,465,129,984 100%  384.97MB/s    0:00:28 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

# this is a sample output for posting here, copying a rhel.iso to test.iso in same directory
```

on my problem server, which is the NFS client connected on a 1gbps wired LAN (the NFS-server is exporting `/bkup`) it shows about 250 MB/sec speed and gets to 100% but then hangs, the prompt does not come back and in any other terminal window if I try to do a `cd /bkup` that hangs.  Also using tab for bash auto completion hangs.  All the while it is hung there is no `/bkup/ron.zip` file shown if I log into the NFS-server and do an `ls /bkup`.  **What is happening?**

Comment: Units? Is gbps actually GB/s or Gb/s? Similarly, are you really getting 250 MB/s or is that actually 250 Mb/s?

Comment: my code posting above is a copy/paste... it is  "MB/s"; simply do an `rsync -P` of anything to see firsthand.  I am not sure what I am really getting because maybe of file cache skewing the number on the high side up front, i dunno

Comment: 250 MB/s is equivalent to 2500 Mb/s, or 2.5 Gb/s. Hence the request for clarification

Comment: I am experimenting with `vm.vfs_cache_pressure`

Comment: With `-P` you're enabling `--progress` and `--partial`.  Rsync copies `ron.zip` to a temporary filename on the destination, and after the contents have been copied, renames the temporary file to the final filename.  Your symptoms suggest the "hang" occurs at the rename step.  What type of filesystem is being exported from the NFS server?  Is it a type that could have trouble performing a hard link to a new filename and an unlink on the old name?  The inability to `cd /bkup` suggests the NFS server is the thing getting into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ‘sync’ mount option

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NFS/Troubleshooting#Intermittent_client_freezes_when_copying_large_files

Comment: what's interesting is on the NFS-server a `exportfs -s` shows `(sync,wdelay,hide,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)`  I believe that happens by default I have to go out of my way to make it `async` which is the only other alternative for that knob to turn.  The `mount` output on the nfs client makes no mention of sync or async.

Comment: **is sync / async a server side or a client side option?**  Can one client mount as sync, and another client mount as async ?

Comment: keep in mind I am having this problem trying to transfer just **one** tar file that is 100gb, and would take ~15 minutes reliably if I were to use `scp` which reports 112 MB/sec.  There is no load on the computers nor the wired LAN network.

Comment: This option `sync/async` can be enabled on the NFS clients, NFS servers, or on both.
I think you have to enable `sync` on the client side in the mount options.

Comment: You should put the solution in the answer and not just like to arch. If arch is down, other users will not see a solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).